# createUserWithEmailAndPassword error operation not allowed (firebase auth enabled)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

I'm new with flutter and firebase. I'm trying to use createUserWithEmailAndPassword function for firebase but when I try to implement the code it's an infinite loop. I used debug mode of android studio and it shows me the errors **ERROR_OPERATION_NOT_ALLOWED** : The given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project. Enable it in the Firebase console, under the sign-in method tab of the Auth section. . It seems to be an errors in the firebase authentification but I already enable the authentification with email and password then I don't understand why there is this issue. I copy-paste the json document and I modified the gradle files too as it is mentionned in the google process.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hey @syndey thomas, kindly add your code to the question so I can render help where needed.

Comment: thank you it concerns several files but ther is the end line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error says the given sign-in provider is disabled for this Firebase project
You have to enable email and password options in your firebase project.

See screenshots on how to do that below:

1) Go to the authentication tab after clicking your firebase project
[image]

2) Select the Sign-In methods tab
[image]

3) Enable sign in with email and password
[image]

If you are still getting the error, Try running `flutter clean` in your project.
I hope this helps

Comment: the problem is I already enabled it on firebase and that's what I don't understand. google say it's ok and flutter says it's not enabled

Comment: Did you add the GoogleInfo.plist file to your project ?

Comment: i had the google-service.json file in /android/app as it is said in firebase. Is it the same file ?

Comment: Yes, it is the same. What could be wrong. Try running flutter clean in your project.

Comment: I don't know it's been 2 days i'm looking for an answer and it seems no one has ever had the same issue. I'm trying that

Comment: OMGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGGG it works well done i couldn't figure it ou myself. A big thank you I can stop hitting my head on the desk. Do you know what causes that ?

Comment: Glad it helped.

Comment: yeah i did it but should I edit my first message with your answer ?

Answer (score 0):

```
 FlatButton(onPressed: () async {
                if(_formKey.currentState.validate()) {

                  setState(() => chargement = true);
                  AuthResult result = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: mdp); //here is the issue

                      await collectionUser.document(_idUser()).setData({
                    'idUser' : _idUser(),
                    'nomComplet' : nomComplet,
                    'emailUser' : email,
                  });

                  if(result == null){
                    setState(() => chargement = true);
                  }
                }
              },
              color: Colors.amber,
              child: Text("inscription"),
              shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0)
              ),
            ),
```

Comment: This isn't detailed enough for me to point out the error. Probably post the code on github and share link here ?

Comment: https://github.com/SydneyTH/harcelement is it ok for you ? its on lib file. I'm new for git too ^^ sorry for the long time

Comment: check my answer , i hope it helps.